# Magento 2 base and thumbnail images are not showing on frontend after migrating form 1.9.3 to 2.3.4

Tags: php, image, magento, magento2, magento-1.9

I know this kind of question were already ask many time and I have tried all of there solutions but didn't work for me so that's why I'm asking this question again.

I migrated my store form 1.9.3 to 2.3.4 every thing goes fine expect product images are not showing up on product detail page.

**Expected Result:**

Show all product with base, small and thumbnail images on frontend

**Things I have tried:**

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- php bin/magento indexer:reindex
- php bin/magento catalog:images:resize (took aprox 50 hours to complete)
- php bin/magento cron:run
- sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} + && chmod u+x bin/magento (doesn't work it give me some errors)
- give 777 permission to the pub/media folder

None of these solutions were work for me.I have 77GB available space on my media disk

I have more then 100K downloadable product catalog on my store.

**Real issue:**
On product detail page magento try to get the image but it give 404 error on the console try to get image form cache folder,
it generate small image when I open the product but not base and thumbnail image.

Any help will be highly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `htaccess` file from your media please check it. If its not their place it on media folder and verify. 
Hope it will fix your issue.